# Why my rebuilded openfl/lime 2.9.1 for haxeflixel always ingores my own androidmanifest uses permissions?

Tags: permissions, android-manifest, haxe, openfl, lime-haxe

I use haxeflixel that create `lime build android` applications.
I rebuild lime 2.9.1 from source that lime can make android target sdk version 26, as google said soon be minimum version for playstore. This is the  [original article](https://fouramgames.com/blog/arcane-android-incantations-legacy-openfl-android-build) .

As result i can make `lime build android` with android target sdk api version 26.

-Project.xml `<android minimum-sdk-version="9" if="android" /> <android target-sdk-version="26" if="android" />`

-AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>`

But, now lime always ignores my own AndroidManifest.xml
-Project.xml `<template path="assets/data/AndroidManifest.xml" rename="AndroidManifest.xml" if="android"/>`

as result, my apk in time of installation show me "app no need special permissions". But my own AndroidManifest.xml have syntax

- AndroidManifest.xml
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

If i switch lime version to "prebuilded lime 2.9.1" installed by default in haxeflixel , which can't make android target sdk version 26, but can only 19, then all work normal. In time of apk installing process i see the messages about require special permissions for app, and android app work as expected.

I test it on both windows / linux , the result is same. Prebuilded lime work done, but rebuilded lime ingnore all uses permissions, but use rebuilded lime i still can set portrait/landscape screen orientation inside my own AndroidManifest.xml.

How fix ingnoring android uses permissions from rebuilded lime side?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the permissions into the `Project.hxml`? Something like:

```
<android permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<android permission="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<android permission="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<android permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<android permission="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<android permission="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```